# HTML5 date input in android browser

Tags: android, html, date, browser

I am building a web page for android user, I use a date form control to allow user input the date, but for most devices, it would not pop out the native date selector, but for some Samsung devices like Note2, it can show the native date selector.

I am wondering is this related by android system version? or related with specific android device? How can I detect if current user have that capability to show the date selector?

Answer (score 1):

right now the level of support for the HTML5 <input type="date"> is very varied so I'd suggest using the jQuery/jQueryUI DatePicker as a more reliable solution

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [How to make the HTML5 input type 'date' trigger the native datepicker on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16865378/how-to-make-the-html5-input-type-date-trigger-the-native-datepicker-on-android#comment24327844_16865378) I was able to find a way to have the native android datepicker experience within a web app.