# How to make the HTML5 input type 'date' trigger the native datepicker on Android?

Tags: android, html

Been trying to use the  element in my web application, which I have tried in these two ways:

1. as a standalone html web page, run on Chrome with the user agent
   set to Android 4.0.2
2. in an android app via an activity java file
   and a res/layout file, run through the emulator with Android 4.1.2

Neither of these two ways work, the datepicker does not pop up the native behavior, just a plain text input box shows up. I have a Samsung Galaxy running Android 4.1.2 and the  tag does display the native behavior (I just visited a random website -not mine- to test this tag)

Is there any other solution than PhoneGap for this problem? I can't believe it is this difficult! It's just a datepicker for heaven's sake..

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946919/invoke-native-date-picker-from-web-app-on-ios-android

Comment: I have read that answer over and over again. The HTML5 input tag for date does trigger native behavior automatically in ios. But not on Android, *why* ? I just tried on my Android phone running 4.1.2 and the w3schools test example for the 'date' type does trigger the native datepicker. But NOT on the emulator, and NOT on the webkit browser with the user agent set.

Comment: I do not want to use phonegap. I need this to be able to run standalone in the browser without any native dependencies. Short of writing a javascript plugin complete with css, etc when the web app is run on an Android device - it really looks like there is nothing else that can be done to help this problem.

Comment: Instead of writing your own javascript plugin, you could always use the [jQuery UI Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/).

Comment: What gets me in my tests on Android 7.1 is that it does show a native date picker, but it's not the cool scrolling one, it's some reduced functionality one where I have to click "+"/"-" to advance each field, or else bring up a keypad entry.